# Entity Framework - Code First Migrations - Duplicate Key Was Found

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an issue migrating my db . Just to say - I am a newbie so please don't judge me very hard . 
Here are my two tables(models) , which are supposed to be with one-to-one-or-zero 
relationship :

```
<Table("User")>
Partial Public Class User
    <Key>
    Public Property UserId As Integer

    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property FirstName As String

    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property LastName As String

    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Username As String

    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Password As String

    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Overridable Property User_Wallet As User_Wallet      
End Class

<Table("User_Wallet")>
Public Class User_Wallet
    <Key, ForeignKey("User")>
    Public Property UserId As Integer
    <DataType(DataType.Currency)>
    Public Property WalletBalance As Decimal
    Public Overridable Property User As User
End Class
```

When I try to apply the following migration :

```
Namespace Migrations
    Public Partial Class _4
        Inherits DbMigration

        Public Overrides Sub Up()
            DropForeignKey("dbo.User_WalletUser", "User_Wallet_WalletId", "dbo.User_Wallet")
            DropForeignKey("dbo.User_WalletUser", "User_UserId", "dbo.User")
            DropIndex("dbo.User_WalletUser", New String() { "User_Wallet_WalletId" })
            DropIndex("dbo.User_WalletUser", New String() { "User_UserId" })
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.User_Wallet")
            DropColumn("dbo.User_Wallet", "WalletId")
            DropTable("dbo.User_WalletUser")
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.User_Wallet", "UserId")
            CreateIndex("dbo.User_Wallet", "UserId")
            AddForeignKey("dbo.User_Wallet", "UserId", "dbo.User", "UserId")
            'DropColumn("dbo.User_Wallet", "WalletId")
            'DropTable("dbo.User_WalletUser")
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub Down()
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.User_WalletUser",
                Function(c) New With
                    {
                        .User_Wallet_WalletId = c.Int(nullable := False),
                        .User_UserId = c.Int(nullable := False)
                    }) _
                .PrimaryKey(Function(t) New With { t.User_Wallet_WalletId, t.User_UserId })

            AddColumn("dbo.User_Wallet", "WalletId", Function(c) c.Int(nullable := False, identity := True))
            DropForeignKey("dbo.User_Wallet", "UserId", "dbo.User")
            DropIndex("dbo.User_Wallet", New String() { "UserId" })
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.User_Wallet")
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.User_Wallet", "WalletId")
            CreateIndex("dbo.User_WalletUser", "User_UserId")
            CreateIndex("dbo.User_WalletUser", "User_Wallet_WalletId")
            AddForeignKey("dbo.User_WalletUser", "User_UserId", "dbo.User", "UserId", cascadeDelete := True)
            AddForeignKey("dbo.User_WalletUser", "User_Wallet_WalletId", "dbo.User_Wallet", "WalletId", cascadeDelete := True)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I get this error in the PackageManager console:

**> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key

> was found for the object name 'dbo.User_Wallet' and the index name
>   'PK_dbo.User_Wallet'. The duplicate key value is (0). Could not create
>   constraint or index. See previous errors. The statement has been
>   terminated.**

My tables were with some data first I tried to apply the migration , when Googling a little and read some posts here , I removed all the data - now the tables are empty , but still I get the same error . 
Anyone can give me a direction where my mistake is ?

Comment: The message looks like there'd be multiple rows in dbo.User_Wallet with UserId=0 (ie not unique so the primary key add fails), but with the tables empty, I can't see how it'd happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I will try Drop - Create the tables again and restart VS to see if it works .

Comment: It worked ! It seems when restarted my Visual Studio the problem was solved automatically :) . I don't know if this was a bug but still restarting it helped .